# How to open a Visual Studio 11 project in visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, backwards-compatibility, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded the Visual Studio 11 Beta last night and started work on a new project, only thing is now I *can't* open the project with Visual Studio 2010, does anyone know away round this or a way to save the project in the Beta to be compatible with "older versions", I have looked and tried but as of yet failed?

Comment: The solution files for VS 10 and VS 11 are compatible. What type of project are you trying to open?

Comment: I have converted a .NET 4 project's solution file to VS11 and reopened in VS10 without problems. Did you convert the project to .NET 4.5?

Comment: Problem solved: I had to ask it to open each seperate file within the project, not sure why but it worked, thank you anyway! For reference if anyone else looks this up the orginal error was "Sorry this file can't be opened because it was created with a newer version of Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this a number of times at work recently. You need to install [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Just open the solution in a text editor
in the second line you can find

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
```

change the version to `11.00` and save it.

Try to open the solution and it works.

Update: the original answer was *wrong*. Unlike the version of Visual Studio, the format version has diverged over time. Check it yourself. The correct version number for VS 2010 solutions is `11.00`, not `10.00` as was originally stated above.

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea; shouldn't be necessary, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not open the VS11 project in VS10 – with error message "The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of this application and cannot be opened".

It helped to change the version number on the first line of .sln file (replace the "Format Version 12.00" with "Format Version 11.00")